# mdb crash dump analysis unable to find panic location on code

Tags: c, debugging, crash-dumps

```
$C 
000002a1060d1ff1 cvm_connectivity_master_check_clbk+4(10002c7bc690, 10010de0afb8, 3ec, 0, , 3000004c790)
000002a1060d20a1 vol_kmsg_purge+0x24(10010a514b60, 10010a514b60, 7c09e860, 1, 7, 6)
000002a1060d2151 vol_kmsg_walk_cbq+0x14(70298670, ffffffffffffffff, 7c09e860, 300000b0240, c09e000, 0)
000002a1060d2201 volkmsg_purge_queues+0x1e8(ffffffffffffffff, 0, 70248, 7024a410,1089d4a0, 70000)
000002a1060d22b1 vol_kmsg_config+0x136c(7024c000, 2, 7c09e860, ffffffffffffffff, 70000, 70000)
000002a1060d2381 volkmsg_cluster_reconfig_exit+0x124(0, 1, 1800, 100103076000,100103010000, ffffffff) 

::status 
debugging crash dump vmcore.2 (64-bit) from c1059-Sun6k-BL0-111011
operating system: 5.11 11.1 (sun4v)
usr/src version: 18481:2838b1a36220:on11u1_24b+1
usr/closed version: 1703:0d660c5b838a:on11u1_24b+1
image uuid: 403b6c7b-c0ae-e971-fbfb-833fec604a72
panic message: BAD TRAP: type=31 rp=2a1060d2750 addr=10002c7bc6b0 mmu_fsr=0
dump content: kernel pages and pages from PID -1

cvm_connectivity_master_check_clbk::dis
cvm_connectivity_master_check_clbk: save %sp, -0xb0, %sp
cvm_connectivity_master_check_clbk+4: ldx [%i0 + 0x20], %i3 >>>>>>>>>>>>>
cvm_connectivity_master_check_clbk+8: mov -0x1, %o2
cvm_connectivity_master_check_clbk+0xc: ld [%i3 + 0x10], %o1
cvm_connectivity_master_check_clbk+0x10:add %i3, 0x14, %l6
cvm_connectivity_master_check_clbk+0x14:call -0x638
cvm_connectivity_master_check_clbk+0x18:mov %l6, %o0
cvm_connectivity_master_check_clbk+0x1c:brz,pn %o0, +0x12c

Printing the addres of the cvm_connectivity_master_check_clbk function.

10002c7bc690/J 
mdb: failed to read data from target: no mapping for address 0x10002c7bc690: 
10010de0afb8/J 
0x10010de0afb8: 0 

3000004c790/J 
0x3000004c790: 2a1060d3ad0

2a1060d3ad0::print struct cvm_diskconn_clbk_arg

cdca_send_buf = sysent32+0x6c0 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>suspected

in the code of the function cvm_connectivity_master_check_clbk() following lines are given

cvm_diskconn_clbk_arg_t *arg_buf=cvm_diskconn_clbk_arg_t *)arg;

cvm_diskconn_clbk_payload_t *rec_buf =(cvm_diskconn_clbk_payload_t *)response;

send_buf = arg_buf->cdca_send_buf; >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> suspected code.

disk = cvm_dc_getdisk(send_buf->cdcp_udid_list,send_buf->cdcp_udid_size, VOLNODEV);
```

Here the question is after looking the crash dump it looks like arg_buf- is creating the problem. If any one knows how to debug in this case let me know it will be very help full for me.

Comment: perhaps you have not allocated memory to pointer `arg_buf` and trying to access element `cdca_send_buf` from this unallocated memory or arg_buf is NULL.

Comment: I suspect this line is creating a problem. But i cann't proof it. cvm_diskconn_clbk_arg_t *arg_buf=cvm_diskconn_clbk_arg_t *)arg; by doing this i am allocating something. to arg_buf but how can i prove it arg_buf isNULL.     when i tried to print the structure 2a1060d3ad0::print struct cvm_diskconn_clbk_arg           cdca_send_buf = sysent32+0x6c0  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> is it some useful to say something.

Comment: try for `printf("%p",arg_buf);` see is value blank??

Comment: Thanks. But this is a transient issue. It doesn't always hit. I am looking the way by looking into crash dump i can say by surety that this line is creating problem.